# @Input solo cambia una vez

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Tengo un componente padre y un componente hijo, el componente padre le pasa parámetros al hijo desde padre.component.ts y el hijo inicializa una variable con los datos del @Imput. Se hace una operación dentro de hijo.component.ts y le pasa el resultado al padre con un EventEmitter. Si los datos que le pasa el hijo al padre están mal, este le hace saber al hijo el error cambiando el valor de un parámetro del componente hijo.
La primera vez que se hace funciona, pero la segunda vez ya no lo hace más, he utilizado ngOnChanges y le he agregado un setter al @Input para mostrar lo que se recibe, pero siempre funciona la primera vez que le paso datos y la primera que los cambios, cuando quiero volverlos a cambiar ni el setter ni el ngOnChanges detectan cambio.

A continuación dejo algo de código.

```
// Este es el componente padre
// Aquí dejo este valor por default para pasarlo así 
setError = false;

// Con este método no importa que me envíe el hijo, siempre le voy a mandar un error
setErrorFunction () {
 this.setError = true;
}

<!-- Esto está en el padre.component.html -->
<app-password-input
 [error]="setError "
 (output)="getData($event)">
</app-password-input>
```

El código del componente hijo sería el siguiente

```
private _error: boolean;

@ViewChild("inputPassword") inputPassword: ElementRef;

@Input() set error(value:boolean) {
    this._error = value;
    console.log("input error", this._error);
  }

@Output() output = new EventEmitter<any>();

form: FormGroup;

ngOnInit(): void {
 this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
  inputPassword: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{8,}$')]]
 });
}

// Gets
get invalidPassword() {
 // Si el password es invalido o es un error
 return this.form.get("inputPassword").invalid || this._error ? true : false;
}

get validPassword() {
 // Si el el password es valido y tampoco es un error
 return this.form.get("inputPassword").valid && !this._error ? true : false;
}

// Cada que se presione una tecla, cambia el valor dado por el padre a un error falso
onKey(password:string) {
 this._error = false;
}
```

Esto es el hijo.component.html

```
<form class="form" [formGroup]="form">
  <input type="password"
   #inputPassword
   formControlName="inputPassword"
   class="form-control"
   [class.is-invalid]="invalidPassword"
   [class.is-valid]="validPassword"
   (keyup)="onKey($event.target.value)">
</form>
```

Como pueden ver, es un input para escribir un password, cuando se muestra por primera vez, la validación hace que se muestre el campo en rojo, pero no tiene un error dado por el padre, si el padre le da un error, al escribir en el campo el error cambia a falso. El padre solo puede cambiar una vez el valor de _error, dentro de padre.component.ts cambia, pero en hijo.component.ts no lo hace.
¿qué podría estar mal?

Answer (score 1):

La solución fue muy simple, quité todos los `@Imput` y creé solo uno de nombre data y tipo `any` sin utilizar un `SET` ni un `ngOnChanges`.

```
@Input() data:any;
```

La variable data contiene un objeto json en el cual viene el atributo error.

```
this.data.error;
```

Ahora cada cambio que hace el padre lo detecta el hijo inmediatamente.

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta que has puesto es valida. Pero te dejo la solución al problema que tenías anteriormente.

Te falta añadir el `getter` para `@Input set error` que devuelva al propiedad `this._error` con esto siempre tendrás acceso al valor que setee al error.

Puedes hacer lo siguiente

```
@Input() 
set error(value:boolean) {
    this._error = value;
    console.log("input error", this._error);
}

get error() {
  return this._error; 
}
```